# GDI+ functionality in .NET CF generic WinCE

Tags: graphics, compact-framework, gdi+, drawing, windows-ce

There is no gdiplus.dll in my WinCE device, Is there any way I can get gdi+ functionality in .NET CF? I'm particularly interested in anti aliased drawing of polygons. (that's all I want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the gdiplus.dll library, there's no way to (easily) do what you want.  You'd have to either manually render in managed code (which will probably be slow) or create your own native library that calls into GDI to do the rendering (essentially creating your own gdiplus subset).